# Why the distance between peaks of the probability distribution function decreases when n increases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

In the solution of Schrödinger Equation for harmonic oscillator why the distance between peaks of the probability distribution function decreases when n increases?

Is there a good reason for it or is it just the consequence of solving the Schrödinger Equation?

Comment: Which probability distribution? What peaks? You must have left something out of the question.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hosc6.html

Comment: Do you know the graph of quantum harmonic oscillator? It is shown in the website. And it is stated that, "the higher the quantum number, the smaller the distance between peaks". I was just wondering if there is a reason for that

Answer (score 1):

> why the distance between peaks of the probability distribution function decreases when n increases?

There's a simple approximate intuition why this happens: energy is inversely proportional to wavelength.

Therefore, the distance between peaks of the probability distribution function decreases when $n$ increases.

Answer (score 0):

"Why" questions can be difficult. You are looking to see that the behavior is the consequence of something familiar. Why does the classical harmonic oscillator spend most of its time near the edge? Because the velocity is lower there.

For the quantum harmonic oscillator, the behavior is the consequence of something unfamiliar. Small "particles" propagate like waves. The relationship of the wave function to physical properties. The uncertainty principle. It can make the answer unsatisfying.

The wave function is related to where the particle is. So you might expect derivatives of the wave function to be related to where it will be soon. Very loosely, big derivatives mean big velocity, which means big momentum and energy. So the momentum and energy operators make a little sense.

For the quantum harmonic oscillator, big n means big energy. So you would expect steep slopes in the wave function. And that leads to many peaks close together.

Answer (score 0):

when you increase $n$ you become more like a classical system, so at $n\rightarrow\infty$ the spectrum becomes essentially continuous. quantum systems should become classical in the limit, that's the basic principle.